# Point windows 10 file history to a different restore location

Tags: windows-10, backup, restore

I've looked all over and can't seem to find an answer of how to navigate the windows 10 file history restore feature with sufficient control and hoping someone can help.  Specifically I would like to figure out how to point the file history program in windows towards a specific location in order to restore files.

Over the last 3 years I have been backing up my windows 10 machine to an external hard drive over the network.  I recently had to change out computers to a refurbished similar model machine.  When I went to restore my backup it is not able to find my backup.  It offers to create a new backup for me, once this is completed I am able to restore from that backup, but it still will not allow me to restore from the previous, complete, backup I have created.

When I look through the back up drive I am able to see the entire file structure of my previous backup that is located under E:\FileHistory*user**computer-name*\Data\C.  I can see all of my previous files and I can copy them over with their associated time stamps.  However, this contains all of the deleted and modified files from 3 years and it would obviously be quite tedious to get rid of all the duplicates.  Thats what a backup program is for right?  Ideally I would want to be able to use the file history program so that it will collate all of this for me so that I can get my most recent environment.  I cannot seem to find anywhere within the windows file history program that allows me to "point" to a certain location in my disk and say "my backup is here!".  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance

Running Windows 10 home 64 bit
OS Build 19041.264
Backup drive is western digital Mybook 3TB